# UITableViewCell - Display Loader whilst pulling data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a fitness plan page with an app which is a UITableViewController with multiple custom uitableviewcells.  It relies on a reasnably large data feed - I'd like to show a loader when accessing this page whilst the data feed is being pulled back from the server.

I have setup a custom uiTableviewCell containg a styled loader message / activity indicator  and would like to show this on load - then when the data is available - refresh the tableview and deque the data into the relevant cells.

Currently I have the following method in my viewdidload method, which currently shows an alert if the feed hasn't completed its load-

```
 [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    if(status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:nil
                              message:@"There is no network connection!"
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];


        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
```

i'd like to alter this to show the loader cell instead - then refresh the view once the data load is complete -

I've altered to the following -

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    if(status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable)
    {
    _WoHpTV.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        workoutBannerCell *cell = [_WoHpTV
                                   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"loaderCell" ];

    }
    else
    {
```

so i've got a refernce to the custom cell in the above - but my question is how do I add it to my TableView?

Comment: What mechanism do you use to access the feed? Does it have a completion callback?

Comment: The usual norm is to show an activity indicator or a spinning loader in center of the screen. Just hide the table and show the indicator once you got the data reload table and unhide table view. Also you are showing the loader cell in wrong place. `AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable` is the state where there s no internet connection.

Comment: @2-Stroker is right. It would be simpler to implement as well.

Comment: cool cheers chaps - yes @Akashg there is a callback method available - adding a activity indicator mid screen also sounds fine - I guess this would be added as a background view of the uitableviewcontroller?

Comment: @Dancer You might also find [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-uirefreshcontrol--mobile-14712) interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i've got a refernce to the custom cell in the above - but my question
>   is how do I add it to my TableView?

You need to implement datasource methods of [`UITableView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource). Since you want to show loading indicators in each of the table cell you would need a temp data (You cannot load 0 cells in table view even to show loader you need some visible cells). In view did load create an array of temp objects and call `reloadData` of tableview.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    [_dataArray addObject:@{@"text":@"text_value"}];
_isDataLoaded = NO;
[_table reloadData];
```

Now this will populate your table with Temp data. Once HTTP call is done set that `BOOL isDataLoaded` to `YES`
Then in Data Source methods -

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (!_isDataLoaded)
        return _dataArray.count; // No data return count for Temp Data
    else
        return _feedArray.count; // Return correct feed items count
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCustomCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell_id"];
    if (cell == nil)
        // Initialise cell here
    if (!_isDataLoaded) { // Data has not yet loaded. Set loaders
        NSDictionary *data = [_dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        // set Cell properties here
    } else {
        // Fetch data from feed array
    }
}
```

And in your question you are trying to detect if feed is loaded or not based on `AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable`. Which is actually incorrect, as this state indicates no internet connection. To track availability of data a simple BOOL as shown above will do.